# jQuery, Html element form external file to string in jquery, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project where i need to get a specific element from an external html file as a string in my jQuery.

As i understand the .get(); function cannot get a specific element (by class or ID) and the .load() can, but loads it directly into the dom of the file.

Is there another function or a way to go about this?

What i need to do is get a specific html element and replace some macros in it with data from an object and then append it to an element (multiple times.) Therefore i cannot just load it in and replace the macros afterwards.

Comment: You need to use `$.get` to retrieve the HTML, and then select the element you want from the returned HTML. This is effectively what `load()` does, just without the final append operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can `.get` it and then only subselect.

```
$.get('myfile.html', function(response) {
  var inside = $(response).find('#inner-id');
  // do stuff with inside...
});
```

Comment: I know its an old post but Im interested. I tried this code but I got an error that says `inner-id is not defined`.

Comment: The parameter there is your CSS selector for the item you want to find, in this case, any HTML tag with the `id="inner-id"` attribute - you can either change the selector argument to something that fits you, or add `id="inner-id"` to the element you are trying to find

Comment: #inner-id must be an element inside myfile.html, right?

Comment: Yes, because we are using the `find` function on the wrapped `$(response)`

Comment: I was doing so but it didnt work. turns out it was a totally different problem all along but thank you.